# HTTPHandler class initialization parameters consist redundant information

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, httphandler

From the official docs on the [HTTPHandler class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler):

> `class logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(host, url, method='GET', secure=False, credentials=None, context=None)`
>
> Returns a new instance of the HTTPHandler class. The host can be of the form `host:port`, should you need to use a specific port number.

There is no documentation of the `url` parameter, and I'm not quite sure what to put there.

For example, if I have a server listening on `http://localhost:8080`, then I think I should set:

- `host='localhost:8080'`
- `url='http://localhost:8080'`

But wouldn't that always be redundant information?

Or else, what should I set the `url` parameter to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the path, like:

```
host='localhost:8080'
path='/'
handler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(host, path)
```

Comment: Thank you. Why just a path, when the argument is `url`?

Comment: Maybe it's not well documented. But `HTTPHandler` internally uses `http.client`, which will handle path. See comment in `putrequest` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/client.py